# Failed to write to a file whose name is in the form of directory/file_name in open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered a problem while developing a complex script, and reproduced it with a few lines:

```
import os

i=2
content_pbs = "test"
os.popen('if [ -d f_bf_'+str(i)+' ]; then rm -rf f_bf_'+str(i)+\
         '; fi; mkdir f_bf_'+str(i)+';')
#Write to a file
f = open('f_bf_'+str(i)+'/my_pbs', 'w')
f.write(content_pbs)
f.close()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
f = open('f_bf_'+str(i)+'/my_pbs', 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f_bf_2/my_pbs'
```

if `popen` is replaced with `system`, no error shows up and the file is correctly written to. Or just modify `f = open('my_pbs', 'w')` while keeping `popen`, no error and the file looks good. If I run the original code with 2.7.10, everything is fine. My question is, what is wrong in my original script? FYI, I use python 3.6.4. Maybe it's a bug in version 3.6.4.

Comment: You didn't wait for the command to finish.

Comment: @user2357112 But after adding `sleep 2` at the end of `popen`, I still got such error.

Comment: Try this code:  `with open('f_bf_'+str(i)+'/my_pbs', 'w') as f: f.write(content_pbs)`

Comment: Side-note: I'd strongly recommend avoiding subprocesses, in favor of `shutil`/`os` functions that perform the same work (e.g. `shutil.rmtree` to delete directory trees, then `os.makedirs`/`os.mkdir` to remake the directory root).

Comment: Why do you want to remove and recreate the directory? Is the directory empty at time you are trying to remove?

Comment: Why are you using the *write this really convoluted mess of code to see if a directory exists, delete it if it does, and then recreate it, execute it via popen, and then open a file in that directory* technique, instead of doing it more easily (and simply) in about three lines of code using `shutil` functionality?

Comment: @rnso Your code does not work. I just want to know what's wrong in my code. I want to delete and recreate the directory every time I run the code, i.e. deleting the old data.

Comment: Is the directory empty when you try to delete it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger @Ken White Thank you for your suggestion, using `shutil`. I will definitely look it up.

Comment: @rnso If the directory is empty, no error shows up, but the file is not written to. So after running the code, no file in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use currently recommended subprocess.Popen ( https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html ), for example as:

```
def rnsystem (cmd, showoutput=True):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              universal_newlines=True, 
                              shell=True)
    (out, err) = p.communicate()
    ret      = p.wait()
    out      = out.split('\n')
    err      = err.split('\n')
    ret_tf   = True if ret == 0 else False
    if showoutput: 
        if ret_tf:
            for o in out: 
                print(o)
        else: 
            for e in err: 
                print(e)
    return {'output': out, 'error': err, 'status': ret, 'status_tf': ret_tf}
```